# NHibernate Insert is Committing but object is not persisted in table

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, forms, orm

When debugging everything appears good. The insert commits and there is no roll back, no exceptions. I sure hope some can help with this.

Here is my call:

```
using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
       {

           _session.Save(calc);
           transaction.Commit();
       }
```

Real simple mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="SigCalculator"
               namespace="SigCalculator.Domain">
```

```
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="Time" />
<property name="Equation" />
```

here's the object:

```
public class Calculation
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public virtual string Equation { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bonehead! Make sure you set your PK to a... PK..

Shheesh..  I need to take a break :)

Comment: Hehe, mistakes like that happen to us all.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call:

```
session.Flush();
```

before the transaction Commit? What is your application's FlushMode set to?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following.. nothing changed.

public void AddCalc(Calculation calc)
       {
           using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
           {

```
           _session.Save(calc);
           _session.Flush();
           transaction.Commit();
       }



   }
```